# Elasticsearch: AngularJS & Aggregations

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch (version 2.2.0) and discovered that angular.js can be used to create front end UI. (I am a complete newbie to angular.js, and overall programing itself).

I am following an online tutorial and cant seem to get the aggregations passed from elasticsearch to the angular object, though I can view the aggregation in curl command on terminal. Is there something wrong, that I can fix. I want to be able to see the aggregations passed to the object, so that I can use it to create a front end UI based filter list.

```
searchApp.service('filterService', [function(){
this.filters ={
    availableFilters:{},
    selectedFilters: []
};


this.findSelectedFilter= function(field,value) {

    var selectedFilters = this.filters.selectedFilters;

    for (var i=0; i<selectedFilters.length; i++) {
        var obj = selectedFilters[i];

        if (obj.field == field && obj.value == value) {

            return i;
        }
    }
        return -1;

};

this.formatFilters = function(aggregations) {

    var self=this;
    var formattedFilters = {};

    for (var aggregation in aggregations) {

        if(aggregations.hasOwnProperty(aggregation)) {

            var filters = aggregations[aggregation].buckets.map(function(obj){

                var isSelected = function() {

                    return self.findSelectedFilter(aggregation, obj.key) == -1 ? false:true;
                };

                return  {

                    value: obj.key,
                    count: obj.doc_count,
                    isSelected: isSelected()
                }
            });

            formattedFilters[aggregations] = filters;
        }
    }
}
}]);
```

(PS: I have seen elastic-UI, which works , but want to try this method). 
Thanks a lot!!